# Probability of a hand containing more clubs than spades in an incomplete deck

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

The problem:

A deck is missing a number of cards. It has S spades, C clubs, and E red cards, for a total of M cards. A side point is that C = S + 1. A hand of N cards is dealt.

A) What is the probability of the player receiving more clubs than spades?

B) What is the probability of the player NOT receiving more spades than clubs?

And now for what I believe to be the solution:

The probability of a hand of N cards containing R spades is

$$
\begin{pmatrix} S \\ R\end{pmatrix} / \begin{pmatrix} M \\ N\end{pmatrix}
$$

Thus, the probability of a hand of N cards containing exactly R spades AND B clubs is in fact the probability of the hand containing R spades, B clubs, and D reds, where D = N - R - B, and so is equal to

$$
\begin{pmatrix} S \\ R\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} C \\ B\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} E \\ D\end{pmatrix}/ \begin{pmatrix} M \\ N\end{pmatrix}^3
$$

I would then need to sum it across all values of B and R where

A) B is greater than R

$$
\sum_{R=1}^S \sum_{B=R+1}^C (\begin{pmatrix} S \\ R\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} C \\ B\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} E \\ D\end{pmatrix}/ \begin{pmatrix} M \\ N\end{pmatrix}^3)
$$

B) B is greater than or equal to R

$$
\sum_{R=1}^S \sum_{B=R}^C (\begin{pmatrix} S \\ R\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} C \\ B\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} E \\ D\end{pmatrix}/ \begin{pmatrix} M \\ N\end{pmatrix}^3)
$$

All that would be left would be to make sure to select meaningful values of R and B (e.g. R + B cannot be greater than N).

Do you agree?

Comment: For the probability that a hand of $N$ contains exactly $R$ spades, the numerator needs to be $\binom{S}{R}\binom{M-S}{N-R}$.

Comment: Andre - would that work in this case, where we are dealing with two things - the number of spades and the number of clubs - and these two events are not independent?

Comment: isnt the numerator i used more like a special case of the formula you suggest? since we need to trisect the hand?

Comment: I was just commenting on the first formula that you gave, which was not right: we need to take account not only of the $R$ spades, but of the rest of the $N$ cards. The other formulas you give are close to correct, with wrong denominators, in all cases it should be $\binom{M}{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a discrete uniform distribution over the set of possible hands. In such a distribution the probability of a set $S$ is the size of $S$ divided by the total number of hands $\binom{M}{N}$ (Not $\binom{M}{N}^3$!). The number of hands with exactly $B$ clubs and $R$ spades is $\binom{C}{B}\binom{S}{R}\binom{E}{N-B-R}$, and so you can indeed get the answer by summing over legal values of $R$ and $B$.

To summarize, your answers are almost correct - you just need to lose the power 3 in the denominator.

Comment: I see... it was a mistake to multiply because the events were not independent. I wonder if there are any other flaws?